# Style sheet is appliped to the cells in QGridLayout instead of the parent container

Tags: qt, signals-slots, moc, qlayout

I have inherited QWidget to make a class called (lets say..) TaskBox.
I've applied a QGridLayout to my TaskBox.
The layout consists of several QLabels.

I've changed the background color of the TaskBox by setting a style sheet for it.
Now it looks like this:

[image]

This is what I want, and I'm happy with it.

The problem is, I want to add Q_OBJECT macro to TaskBox class. (because I need to use signals and slots)

After adding Q_OBJECT macro, my TaskBox objects becomes like this:

[image]

It looks like the style sheet is broken into cells in QGridLayout.

Here is my TaskBox class:

```
class TaskBox : public QWidget{

Q_OBJECT

public:


    QLabel * title;
    QLabel * description;
    QGridLayout * layout;


   TaskBox(){

       layout = new QGridLayout();

       setRandomColor();   //Function is available below


       title = new QLabel("Something");
       title->setStyleSheet("color:white;");


       description = new QLabel("Something again");
       description->setStyleSheet("color:white;");


       layout->addWidget(title, 0,0);
       layout->addWidget(description,1,0);


       layout->setColumnStretch(0,2);
       layout->setColumnStretch(1,1);

       setLayout(layout);


   }


   void setRandomColor(){

        setStyleSheet("border-radius: 5px;background-color:rgb(" + QString::number((rand() % 255)) + "," + QString::number((rand() % 255)) + "," + QString::number((rand() % 255)) + ");");
   }


};
```

I can't understand what's going on.
Thanks for any of your helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you subclass `QWidget`, you need to override the [`paintEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) function to get the stylesheets to work properly.

Here is how you should do it:

```
void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
 {
     QStyleOption opt;
     opt.init(this);
     QPainter p(this);
     style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
 }
```

Comment: What exactly does this do? I never though a custom paintEvent was needed for using stylesheets

Comment: @yankee2905 Look in [the qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-stylable-widgets). Look at the part about `QWidget`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using property names to remove the ambiguity of what you're setting the StyleSheet for

In you TaskBox constructor:

```
setProperty("taskbox", true);
```

And then:

```
   void setRandomColor(){

        setStyleSheet("*[taskbox=\"true\"] {border-radius: 5px;background-color:rgb(" + QString::number((rand() % 255)) + "," + QString::number((rand() % 255)) + "," + QString::number((rand() % 255)) + ");}");
   }
```